# What is the girl's name?

Tags: mathematics, cipher

I have just met a girl in a bar, and got her number after some non-sense talk. She gave her number and said that the number after the area code is also her name, and she wants me to call her only if I can figure out her name:

> 2784783

Before calling her again, I need to figure out her name! Help please.

**Hint**: Girl's name has 7 letters as the number of digits. And it is more math than crypto.

**Hint 2**: The first letter of her name is B.

Comment: I'm from the UK so I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, am I right in saying '278' is the area code?

Comment: @BreakingMyself No, the area code has not been included, hence "the number *after* the area code".

Comment: @Mordechai I just figured that would be the entire phone number as it wasn't specified. Our numbers are written/formatted differently here so I wouldn't know by just looking lol.

Comment: Running the entire number through this : http://www.aer.org, it looks like 'Sue' is the only sensible option.

Comment: Obviously, her name must be 'two million seven hundred eighty thousand four thousand seven hundred and eighty three'. An unusual choice, perhaps, but who are we to judge? :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Girl's name is:

> Barbara

I have reached this solution by:

> Taking the modulo of the first number (2) and the number of letters in the alphabet corresponding to that number
>
>  2 % 26 = 2 = B -> The second letter in the alphabet
>
>  I then compounded on each number thereafter.
>  27 % 26 = 1 = A
>  278 % 26 = 18 = R
>  2784 % 26 = 2 = B
>  27847 % 26 = 1 = A
>  278478 % 26 = 18 = R
>  2784783 % 26 = 1 = A
>  Hence the letter spell Barbara

Comment: This annoys me lol, nice job assuming this is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Great first answer! Hope you stick around!

Comment: well done! this is the answer I am looking for :) glad someone solved it, I didnt want to give more hints.

Answer (score 5):

I think the girl is called:

> **Artiste**

Which is a bit unusual but who am I to judge? I decoded this using ideas left in the comments:

> Using each letter as one of the telephone keys (2 is ABC, 3 is DEF, etc) I was able to find 2=A 7=R 8=T 4=I 7=S 8=T 3=E.

Comment: Unless @Oray has a crush on a girl named Artiste right now, I doubt he would choose such a random and possibly non existent name for his riddle. Also math needs to be used to solve the problem.

Comment: I Googled it before I posted to be sure, it's a real name but not very common. If there is another solution I'll happily delete mine.

Comment: There is no need to delete, if all wrong answers were deleted from stackexchange, it would be quite a sad and lonely website.

Comment: unfortunately this is not an answer i am looking for. As @stackreader stated math is included in this.